# What popup box does Zoom use?

Tags: javascript, popup

Anyone who uses Zoom Join Meeting URLs would have seen this box:

---

[image: Zoom Popup Box]

---

This can not be inspected, so it must be from the browser, but it doesn't look like any other types of browser popups (`alert`, `confirm`, and `prompt`).  Does anyone know what type of popup box is this?

Comment: They are not using any popup. The browser natively asks the user permission to use an app if it's installed. Zoom simply used deep linking, with the [`zoomus://` protocol](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/additional-tips/launch-zoom-client-from-your-app#method-2-use-url) instead of `https://`